# How to add an action in the contacts list action drop down menu

Tags: contacts, custom, actions

I need to add actions in the contacts list drop down action menu.
As an example, if I make a contacts search I got a contacts list result. Then on the contacts list I can choose an action like export contacts. I would like to add actions on thé action list.
Does someone has an idea on how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome Bruno. You would have to modify the action menu functionnality. Have you looked into the [dev documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/)?

Comment: Here is the specific page: https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_summaryActions/